# Is it possible to merge Data from List and Data Extension via query in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, list

Is it possible to merge Data from List and Data Extension via query in Marketing Cloud?

I need to create a Data Extension with SubscriberKey from the list and FirstName from the Data Extension. Which is the best way to achieve this task?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found an answer and could execute the task:

```
SELECT
  l.SubscriberKey,
  c.FirstName,
  c.EmailAddress
FROM
  _ListSubscribers l WITH (NOLOCK)
    inner join Tb_Contact c on c.SubscriberKey = l.SubscriberKey
WHERE
  l.ListName in ('List1', 'List2','List3')
```

Maybe I will help others with the same question.

Thanks.